# Combining two columns with the same name in a df

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Id columns in my df which are split into either a Id or NaN.

| Date | ... | ID | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/12/2019 | ... | DE1253 | NaN |
| 12/12/2018 | ... | eg562r | NaN |
| 12/12/2021 | ... | gse233 | NaN |
| 12/12/2019 | ... | NaN | wefg32 |
| 12/11/2010 | ... | NaN | rte422 |
| 12/10/2021 | ... | NaN | 3fdes4 |

How can I combine these two fields into one ignores the NaN so that there the desired output is

| Date | ... | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/12/2019 | ... | DE1253 |
| 12/12/2018 | ... | eg562r |
| 12/12/2021 | ... | gse233 |
| 12/12/2019 | ... | wefg32 |
| 12/11/2010 | ... | rte422 |
| 12/10/2021 | ... | 3fdes4 |

Any help would be much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with `groupby`

```
out = df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).first()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the columns to be merge have identical names and non overlapping data:

```
out = df.stack().unstack()
```

Or, to keep the original order of the columns:

```
df.stack().unstack()[df.columns.unique()]
```

output:

```
         Date  ...      ID
0  12/12/2019  ...  DE1253
1  12/12/2018  ...  eg562r
2  12/12/2021  ...  gse233
3  12/12/2019  ...  wefg32
4  12/11/2010  ...  rte422
5  12/10/2021  ...  3fdes4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another shorter solution. My ID column names are `ID1` and `ID2`. For some reason I can't create 2 column with same name. Also, you can drop `ID1` and `ID2`. I kept them for completeness.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ["12/12/2019", "12/12/2018", "12/12/2021", "12/12/2019",
                                 "12/11/2010", "12/10/2021"],
                       'ID1': ['DE1253', 'eg562r', 'gse233', np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
                       'ID2': [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,'wefg32', 'rte422', '3fdes4']})
    df['ID'] = df.ID1.combine_first(df.ID2)
    print(df)



dates     ID1     ID2      ID
0  12/12/2019  DE1253     NaN  DE1253
1  12/12/2018  eg562r     NaN  eg562r
2  12/12/2021  gse233     NaN  gse233
3  12/12/2019     NaN  wefg32  wefg32
4  12/11/2010     NaN  rte422  rte422
5  12/10/2021     NaN  3fdes4  3fdes4
```